# Find out field of object in SortedList

Tags: c#, linq, sortedlist

```
struct SessionStruct
{
   object Obj;
   string token;
}
SortedList <string,SessionStruct> sessionsList=new SortedList<string,SessionStruct>();
SessionStruct structObj;
```

I need to find out if `sessionList` has `structObj` where `structObj.token="somestring"` after I fill the     `sessionList`.
I can get `array` of `SessionStruct` and do `foreach` looking for required token. However I am wondering if there is any elegant way to get this task done. If there is any way using LINQ?

Comment: Have you tried `sessionList.Where(s => s.token == "somestring")` ?

Comment: What are you using as `Key` in your `SortedList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

`sessionsList.Any(ss => ss.Value.token == "somestring")` will give you a bool

Comment: Close, but `ss` will be of type `KeyValuePair<string, SessionStruct>`

Comment: Thank a lot! Remark: sessionList.Any(s=>s.Value.token=="somestring"). VS accepted this code.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `sessionsList.Values.Any(ss => ss.token == "somestring")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your struct's properties are declared as public (in your example it is not), you can do the following:

```
SortedList<string, SessionStruct> sessionsList = new SortedList<string, SessionStruct>();
var exists = sessionsList.Any(s => s.Value.token.Equals("somestring"));
```

Your `struct`, with public properties:

```
public struct SessionStruct
{
    public object Obj;
    public string token;
}
```